# log4j2 the logger get by Slf4j LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory can only read default log4j.xml without profile

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, slf4j

Use log4j2 in SpringBoot project with test profile,

`org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("xxx")` can get test profile LoggerContext and read configuration from `log4j2-test.xml`.

But

`org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().getLogger("xxx")` can only get current LoggerContext and read configuration from `log4j2.xml`.

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("xxx"); // log4j2-test.xml
LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().getLogger("xxx"); // log4j2.xml
```

Is it a bug of log4j2?

I tested `LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().getLogger("xxx")` with Logback, Logback can choose `log4j2-test.xml` properly.

SpringBoot version: `2.4.5`

Add some background to help more people: `ParSeq` framework prints logs by `LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().getLogger("xxx")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a bug of log4j2:
[JIRA_LOG4J2-3083](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3083)

Answer (score 0):

No, this would not be a bug in Log4j. Log4j knows nothing about Spring profiles and does not incorporate them in its logic of locating a configuration file.

The methods in LoggerFactory that you are calling are static. That means they are implemented by SLF4J. The [SLF4J source](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.java#L356) shows that getLogger("XXX") does

```
    public static Logger getLogger(String name) {
        ILoggerFactory iLoggerFactory = getILoggerFactory();
        return iLoggerFactory.getLogger(name);
    }
```

which is exactly the same as what you are manually doing in your second call, so I cannot see how there could be any difference between them.

I also doubt that Logback can choose log4j2-test.xml properly since that would be an invalid configuration file for Logback.

Comment: The magic is in Log4jLoggerFactory.java of log4j-slf4j-impl. Although these two methods eventually call the same method, their call stacks are different.   `Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext()` will choose context by method call stack. But it only support `LoggerFactory.getLogger("xxx")`